# Pass value from one Tabbar controller to another controller in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Pass value from one TabBar controller to another Controller and set value.

I have 5 UIViewcontroller which is added to UITabBarController.

```
controller1 = new Controller1();
controller2 = new Controller2();
controller3 = new Controller3();
controller4 = new Controller4();
controller5 = new Controller5();

controller1.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("first", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/first.png"), 0);
controller5.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("second", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/four.png"), 1);
controller5.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("third", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/four.png"), 2);
controller5.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("four", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/four.png"), 3);
controller5.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("five", UIImage.FromFile("/Images/four.png"), 4);

var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
        controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4, controller5 
    };
    ViewControllers = tabs;
```

controller1 have Label

```
UILabel lbl_Label1;  
string setValue = "Welcome";
lbl_Label1.Text = setValue;
```

from controller3 change controller1 Label value

create Object from Controller1 and set Label text.

```
Controller1 controller1 = new Controller1();
controller1.lbl_Label1.Text = "Bye";
this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Which is not working.   Its shows same `Welcome` message for the label of controller1.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you create another instance of Controller1.

Usually, i like to use notification in this cases, try this:

Add this code in Controller3 when you want to change the text label:

```
NSDictionary dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"new label text"
                                              forKey:@"newText"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeTextLabel" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

And this in viewDidLoad of Controller1

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeTextLabelMethod:) name:@"changeTextLabel" object:nil];
```

When you send notification from Controller3, Controller1 calls the method "changeTextLabelMethod" and you can do everything you want:

For Example, in Controller1:

```
-(void) changeTextLabelMethod:(NSNotification *) notification{
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
    lbl_Label1.Text = [dict objectForKey:@"newText"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While notifications could work, there is a much simpler way to do this:

You can access the viewControllers in your tab bar by calling on tabBarController --> viewControllers.

So:

```
this.tabBarController.viewControllers
```

should give you an array of viewControllers. If you are trying to modify the first view controller based on something happening in another viewController, you could do this:

```
Controller1 *myController1Instance = (Controller 1 *) this.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
myController1Instance.lbl_Label1.Text = "Bye";
this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Assuming that lbl_Label1 is a public property on Controller1.

Comment: I am using Xamarin C# Lanauge. still its not working.. for me.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part, sorry I'm unfamiliar with that language. Were you able to understand what I did in Objective-C though? maybe there is an equivalent you can find in Xamarin?